# Workbook.SaveAs() to different folder in Office 2011 for Mac

Tags: vba, save-as, excel-2011

How to save xls to another folder?

When I use "/" in save path it replaces then with ":". When I try to use "\" it saves the file with "\" in file name.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Application.PathSeparator property and as an added bonus it'll be platform agnostic.

`myPath = "myDirectory" & Application.PathSeparator & "mySubDirectory" & Application.PathSeparator & "myFileName"`

Comment: +1 If you get tired of typing `Aplication.PathSeparator` (oops) then assign it to a string variable with a shorter name, e.g.  `Dim ps As String: ps = Application.PathSeparator`. Or even better: `Replace("myDirectory\mySubDirectory\myFileName","\",Application.PathSeparator)` to avoid all the annoying string concatenation.